# Change directory of current terminal with python cli tool

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface

I am working on a simple cli tool for changing project directories of the current terminal window. The cli tool is writen in python using the click package. From what I have seen I don't think it is possible to change the directory but maybe someone has so insight that would help.

For the example workflow

```
$ pwd
/home/username
$ grab open projectA
$ pwd
/home/username/projects/projectA
$ grab open projectB
$ pwd
/home/username/projects/different/location/projectB
```

The things that I do know.

- Using python `os.chdir(path)` only works in side the current script and has no affect on the terminal once executed.
- Trying python `subprocess.run(['cd', 'path'])` will throw a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd'`
- Running `$ source change_dir.sh` will work on the command line but try in a `subprocess` the same `FileNotFoundError` will be raised. Note, change_dir.sh is a simple script that that uses cd to change path.

I am really looking for a way around this issue or to be told this is not possible to do.
The next thing I might try is lunching a bash shell in the terminal similar to what happens when launching a virtual environment with python. 
Off the bat this feel like the wrong way to me.

Any advice is will be helpfully.

Comment: `cd` and `source` are shell builtins, not freestanding commands that can be executed at will by non-shells.

Comment: Been shell builtins makes sense thank you. Than would explain why the virtual environment activate script has  
```# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
 # you cannot run it directly```
I guess I may look at a different idea. Maybe some thng like `grab path projectA | cd` is possible. I ned to look into this.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm trying to do the same thing but from a swift cli. In the worst case i want to tell applescript to open a new tab and run a cd command

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function

```
grab() {
    case "$1" in
        open)
            cd $(command grab open "$2");;

        *)
            command grab "$@";;
    esac
}
```

load it in you bash

```
$ . grab.sh
```

then, when you run

```
$ grab open projA
```

will change the dir, and for any other subcommand

```
$ grab other whatever
```

it will run `grab`.